# Any solutions for disabling the new WhatsApp feature that shows when the message was read?

Tags: settings, whatsapp-messenger

The last seen status can be disabled on WhatsApp at the chat settings. Any way I can disable the two blue ticks that appear on the other person's app  that shows the read time of the message?

Comment: No... We need to wait until someone hack this feature ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do it now. They rolled out Version 2.11.444 with an option to turn off **Read receipts** under the privacy settings. The update is not available through the Play Store at the time of me writing this answer, though - you have to download and install the apk from their official website.

For more info check http://codezag.com/disabling-blueticks-whatsapp-turn-off-read-reciepts/

Answer (score 0):

Currently enabling the flight mode before reading a message is the only existing solution...